# How to add trigger sequence used Oracle ADF

Tags: groovy, oracle-adf

how to written a trigger for my application to generate numbering for records using a sequence Before Insert used in entity Business Ruels type BeforeInsert.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a trigger.
You can simply use the Groovy expression to read the value from DB sequence.

### Groovy code :-

(new oracle.jbo.server.SequenceImpl("EMPLOYEES_SEQ",adf.object.getDBTransaction())).getSequenceNumber()

---

### Java Code :-

SequenceImpl seq = new SequenceImpl("EMPLOYEES_SEQ",getDBTransaction().getRootApplicationModule());
BigDecimal EmpIdNumber = new BigDecimal(seq.getSequenceNumber().toString());

```
  setEmployeeId(EmpIdNumber);
```

[here , "EMPLOYEES_SEQ" is the name of the sequence , please replace it with your own sequence .]